# SceneKit - What orthographicProjection to use for 1:1 points to SceneKit position ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, 3d, scenekit

What orthographicProjection does one have to use to be able to make a 2D application in SceneKit with 1:1 SceneKit points to screen points/pixels ratio?

Example:
I want to position something at (200, 200) on the screen and I want to use a SCNVector with (200, 200, 0) for it. What orthographicProjection do I need for this?

Comment: Hello, what is the relationship between viewport and orthographicScale? I'm confuse about that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want an orthographic projection where a unit of scene space corresponds to a point of screen space, you need a projection where the left clipping plane is at zero and the right clipping plane is at whatever the screen's width in points is. (Ditto for top/bottom, and near/far doesn't matter so long as you keep objects within whatever near/far you set up.)

For this it's probably easiest to set up your own projection matrix, rather than working out what `orthographicScale` and camera position correspond to the dimensions you need:

```
GLKMatrix4 mat = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                     0, self.view.bounds.size.height,
                                     1, 100); // z range arbitrary
cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform = SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4(mat);
// still need to position the camera for its direction & z range
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 50);
```

Comment: This is nice, thank you! I found out in the meantime that one can use the height of the screen / 2.0 as the orthographicScale. I'm wondering if SceneKit is able to do certain optimization if you set the orthographicProjection flag to true. That's why I kept trying. What do you think will lead to better performance?

Comment: The `orthographicProjection` + `orthographicScale` property combination is probably just a shortcut for setting up a projection matrix based on the camera direction & viewport, so there should be no performance difference.

Comment: Okay cool, I just don't have enough insight into SceneKit yet, thanks! Where did you learn about it? Just from the docs?

Comment: @Max also need to learn about `orthographicScale` for directional lights so any insight about how you learned to use this would be great. there is scant documentation unfortunately on scenekit.

Comment: @rickster Hello, what is the relationship between viewport and orthographicScale? I'm confuse about that

Comment: @rickster Could you help me out If you have time. My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428397/confused-about-orthographic-projection-of-camera-in-scenekit