# Creating and rendering SceneKit nodes using pixel/point values?

Tags: ios, macos, scenekit

I'm trying to use SceneKit to render some highly geometric and skeuomorphic UI elements. So far I've figured out how to use `SCNView` to render the scene, but I've run into two problems:

1. SceneKit geometry is measured in meters, which means having to do point conversion any time geometry is manipulated or created.
2. `SCNView` seems to perform it's own scaling on `SCNScene` it renders, without any clear API to disable or control that scaling. This makes it more difficult to map the geometry to the screen.

What techniques exist to create scenes in such a way that easily map to screen geometry?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to accomplish. There are the [`projectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint) and the [`unprojectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522631-unprojectpoint) methods to convert between screen coordinates and SceneKit units though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the answer I was looking for  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456861/scenekit-what-orthographicprojection-to-use-for-11-points-to-scenekit-positio?rq=1).